# how to find how many times a word occurs in the html table row which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html

i wrote a xlst code to transform xml to html which creates lots of tables in html.

there is a column by name 'Type' in the table. which contains words

1) Trace
2) Verification
3) Action

the above 3 word's will repeat many times in the same column of the table.
my requirement is to display how many times each word appeared in the column

and i should show the count immediately when the html page get loaded

---

Here goes the general schema of the tables

```
/*Table Schema*/
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Time</th>
 <th>Position</th>
 <th>Type</th>
 <th>Message</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>Action</td>
 <td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>Verification</td>
 <td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>Trace</td>
 <td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>....</td>
 <td>Error</td>
 <td>....</td>
</tr>
```

The above is the general schema of the table and the words action, trace, error, verification occurs many times in a single table 
There will be arround 5 tables of each type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/5/ [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/5/)

You can do this using jquery

Consider the example html

```
  <table>
<tr>
    <th>Trace</th>
    <th>Verification </th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>CC</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Some</th>
    <th>Thing</th>
    <th>Dont</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>CC</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The js will be

```
   $(document).ready(function ()
{
    getOccurance("CC");
    function getOccurance(word)
    {
        $("table").each(function (tindx, tobj)
        {
            var noOfOccurance = 0;
            $("tr td:gt(1)", $(tobj)).each(function (ind, obj)
            {
                if (word == $.trim($(obj).text())) noOfOccurance++;
            });

            alert("Word " + word + " occurs " + noOfOccurance + " times in table  " + (tindx + 1));
        })
    }

})
```

​

```
​
```

[Demo of getting Count in loading itself](http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/7/)

[Demo of getting count from every tables](http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/8/)

[Demo of getting count from each tables and showing result in html itself](http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/10/)

Comment: For getting count as soon as page loads , call the function getOccurance in the document.ready function rather than in the click function ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer Akhil. There are more than 20 tables in the same html page which contains the same words. i need to get the count of each word in the particular table (not all the tables) and display that at the end of each table

Comment: Your code worked like a charm but as i told before it showing the count of the word in all the tables. I want it individually. Thanks in advance

Comment: use some selection criteria  here $("table tr td:gt(1)") , for selecting individual table ..
Pls paste some exaples of table structure so that i can help you ..

Comment: i edited my question and provided the default schema of the table. i think the code provided for the second time may help me i will try it out and get back to you :) Thanks for the Answer

Comment: and also please make necessary changes to your code so that number of occurance  times can be show on html page(not as a alert) and for all the words for example it should show.. No of Actions: 13 times No. of Verifications: 15 times and No of Errors 12 times... for each and every table .. :) Sorry for disturbing

Comment: @Trini update the fiddle in which i shown u the demo with your html structure , then i can help you ...

Comment: Thanks.. I updated the fiddle and here is the link for it http://jsfiddle.net/PhB7x/9/

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the text of that row into a variable and do a match on the word needed, for example "Trace". Something like the following:

```
var row = $('tr#action').text();
var count = row.match(/Trace/g);
```

Comment: sorry i wrote my query in hurry and made mistakes while expressing it. now i made my question and query very clear now please guide me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example :

http://jsbin.com/otezes/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rows = $("#aaa tr");
  var arr = {};
  rows.each(function(){
    var val = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
    if (val === "") return;
    if (typeof(arr[val])!= "undefined"){
      arr[val] = ++arr[val];
    }
    else{
      arr[val] = 1;
    }
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

});
```